# JAVAFX Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"

Tags: javafx

I was trying to add 10 records to my table when the "Page-down" button is pressed, the same for the "Down-arrow" is pressed. I keep getting the Exception error while I'm trying to add more records.
I am using a cursor mapping for each table.

```
      this.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            switch (event.getCode()){
                case PAGE_DOWN:

                            try {

                                if (resultSet.getRow() == numberOfRows) break;
                                if (((CanvasTableView) event.getSource()).getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow() > resultSet.getRow() - 17) {
                                    Object object =  table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().get(); // get the focus cell
                                    int index = table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().get();    // get the focus cell

                                    int cursor_index = buffer_paging.get(table);  //cursor index


                                    resultSet.absolute(cursor_index);
                                    System.out.println("Row:   " + resultSet.getRow());
                                    ArrayList<Row> data = dataBaseArrayListByNumber(rs, rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(), 17,cursor_index);
                                    table.getItems().addAll(data);
                                    table.refresh();
                                    System.out.println("Fuck yuval:  " + ((CanvasTableView) event.getSource()).getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow());
                                    buffer_paging.put(table, cursor_index+10);
                                    System.err.println("Row:   " + resultSet.getRow());

                                    System.out.println(index);
                                }
                            }
                             catch (Exception e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                    break;
                case PAGE_UP:   System.err.println("Page up is pressed"); break;

                case DOWN:

                    try {
                    if (resultSet.getRow() == numberOfRows) break;
                    int focus_cell = ((CanvasTableView) event.getSource()).getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
                    int cursor_index = buffer_paging.get(table);  //cursor index
                    int rowNumber = table.getItems().size();

                    if (focus_cell == rowNumber-1 || focus_cell== rowNumber){
                        ArrayList<Row> data = dataBaseArrayListByNumber(rs, rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(), 1,cursor_index);
                        table.getItems().addAll(data);
                        table.refresh();
                        int new_cursor = cursor_index+1;
                        buffer_paging.put(table, new_cursor);

                    }
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    break;


        }

    });
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 16
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9537)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2471)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:413)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:439)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

My function for adding data:

```
 private ArrayList dataBaseArrayListByNumber(ResultSet resultSet, int columnCount,int count,int cursor_index) throws SQLException {

    ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>();
    resultSet.absolute(cursor_index+1);

    while (count>0&& resultSet.next()) {
        HashMap<String, Double> columnData = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            String s = String.valueOf(i);
            double x = resultSet.getDouble(i);
            columnData.put(String.valueOf(i), resultSet.getDouble(i));
        }
        Row row = new Row(columnData);
        data.add(row);
        count--;
    }



    return data;
}
```

Anyone has an idea why I'm keep getting those exceptions?

Comment: Are you using threads? In my experience, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` where only JavaFX code is present in the stack trace indicates a threading problem. Make sure you only update the UI from the FX thread.

Comment: How can I make sure that the other thread is completely finished and just then handle the setOnKeyHandler ?

Comment: use javafx concurrency support - and stick to java naming conventions!